# How to authenticate through basic auth?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, basic-authentication

When I try to build a docker image which pulls a base-trusty package from internal server I get:

> ERROR: Service 'yldrdashboardservice' failed to build: Get 
>   https://repo.domain.com/v2/base-trusty-python27/manifests/latest: no
>   basic auth credentials

This is how I build the image in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
yldrdashboardservice:
    container_name: yldrdashboardservice
    build:
        context: ./yldrdashboardservice
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
        APP_ENV: local
    ports:
        - "5000:6003"
    restart: always
    links:
        - mysql
        - mongodb
```

How do I make it prompt for authentication here? Obviously I don't want to store my credentials as raw text in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: I think the only way is to run docker login on the system to get the auth done, no option to prompt user for auth

Comment: But by default it will store the credentials in `$HOME/.docker/config.json`, right?

Comment: Yes, depending on the OS. Windows will be different. But for mac and linux it would be this. Mac will have the auth in keychains though

Comment: @TarunLalwani any idea of how is this in windows 10?